# wordpress plugin to pass data from jquery to php then save to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am new to this topic. I tried with the following example

created a plugin folder in plugins folder "abc-referer"

created a php file name with "abc-referer.php" and entered following php code

abc-referer.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
```

In the same folder i created a jquery file named "my_query.js" and entered following code

```
$.post( "referer.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });

});
```

In the same folder i created a file named with "referer.php" to get values posted from jquery,

```
echo $POST['name'] . ' at ' . $POST['time'];
//save to database functionality.
```

I don't know where i did mistake. my_query.js is loading correctly. Please give me correction on this to work perfect.

Comment: `$.post( "referer.php"` - that is likely not the correct relative URL. The base path is that of whatever WP page you are currently on, _not_ the location of your JavaScript file.

Comment: And the _correct_ way to use AJAX in plugins is the following, btw. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: $.post( "referer.php" - Could you please give the correct relative url..

Comment: Probably easiest if you use a path beginning with `/`, so that it refers to the domain root - then you don't have to worry about what page you are currently on any more. So `/wp-contents/plugins/...` - and then whatever the path to your script file actually is.

Comment: I added / before referer.php and tested script. The output of referer.php is not displaying. Can you please check once entire script and give what modification will make work that makes it success.

Comment: full jquery script
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$.post( "/referer.php;?>", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });

});

Comment: _"I added / before referer.php"_ - that can of course not be the correct path, because that file is not located in the web root of your domain, but as you said yourself, _"created a plugin folder in plugins folder `abc-referer`"_ And as I already said, the base URL to the plugins folder is `/wp-contents/plugins/`

Comment: "<?php echo plugins_url( 'abc-referer/referer.php', __FILE__ ); ?>", is this correct one. I tried but i am not getting out put of referer.php

Answer (score 0):

I try to do the same staff, bro. But correct path is far away from your try.
The easiest way is  `http://uzx.com/wp-contents/plugins /abc-referer/referer.php` or what domain you bought. But this solution is not proffesional at all and do not allow to give it to commercial purpose.
use this code `url('<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "ulica.jpg"; ?>') or src='<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "ulica.jpg"; ?>' )`
look at detail `'' || ""` make big differ because of its power.  `' '` is stronger and take everything as it is written. What's more, you should avoid situation like using `' '` more then once due to the fact it close the code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).